Failed Load Plugin with text box in Mosaico Templates
I am currently working on creating email templates using Mosaico Templates in CiviCRM. However, whenever I attempt to add text to a textbox. Click Save. Then try to edit the template again, I get flagged with the following error:
Failed to load plugin: civicrmtoken from url https://website.com/
wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/dist/rs/plugins/civicrmtoken/plugin.min.js

Also, when I attempt to look for the above directory path in my File Manager, I can't seem to find the 'plugins' folder after the 'rs' folder.
If anyone could help figure out the cause of my problem that would be greatly appreciated!

It's strange that the path starts with "content", usually it's "wp-content". Check your config?

Whoops, I missed typed the error message, the path does indeed start with "wp-content"
Failed to load plugin: civicrmtoken from url https://website.com/wp-content/uploads/civicrm/ext/uk.co.vedaconsulting.mosaico/packages/mosaico/dist/rs/plugins/civicrmtoken/plugin.min.js
Also fixed it in the post

Ah I see. To be honest I don't know what "civicrmtoken" is. It doesn't exist in a "standard" install. Maybe you have another extension installed and it requires creating the plugins folder and copying files in there?

I was able to resolve this issue by simply uninstalling and reinstalling the Mosaico extensions.

Appears that this was actually a temporary fix. The template was good for a day or so, but eventually the message came back up again.
